# How to create user/allowed port policies in SELinux?

Tags: linux, security, selinux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Restrict User Access to Certain Ports](https://serverfault.com/questions/344161/restrict-user-access-to-certain-ports)

I have been looking at the SELinux documentation for allowing all user processes to only bind on certain ports.

How can I say, USERA can only listen on port 6000; USERB can only listen on port 6001?

Comment: I know that you can restrict *specific* applications run by certain users to certain network ports, but I'm not sure about users in general.  Can you tell us more about what you're doing and trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to limit SSH from only creating remote tunnels on certain ports. I guess "all user processes" premise is unnecessary.